# Aligning JButtons

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, layout

I'm not sure why I can't adjust the location of my buttons in the code below.  I've got a couple of lines that set the boundries, but I must be missing something.

```
public DayGUI()
      {  
         mainFrame = new JFrame("What Kind Of Day Are You Having?");  
         btnGood = new JButton("Good");  
         btnBad = new JButton("Bad");

         btnGood.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 20);
         btnBad.setBounds(10, 30, 80, 20);

       Container c = mainFrame.getContentPane();  
       c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
       c.add(btnGood);  
       c.add(btnBad);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can align your buttons using a `GridLayout`, a `GridBagLayout`, a `SpringLayout`, a `GroupLayout`, and others.

[This is a tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) on GridBagLayout.  [Here is one](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) on GridLayout.  [Here is one](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) on GroupLayout.

[This is the overview](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) on layout managers.  Layout managers allow you to define components in a container in relationship to the container and each other.  They each have their own strengths and weaknesses.

For your needs I would consider GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a layout manager: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Answer (score 1):

You used `FlowLayout` as layout manager. This layout manager don't resize the components to fit all the same size. Instead of `setBounds` you should use `setPreferredSize`.

Answer (score 0):

FlowLayout assumes the "prefered size" for the component when laying them out. Set it
properly and it should just work.

the `setBound` call will be ignored as soon as the layout manager does his work.