# How to align two JButtons to be right aligned?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

So currently my program shows only one of the buttons in the bottom right hand of the GUI. But I want to show both buttons in the bottom right hand corner. Any ideas how to set **both** buttons to the right corner? Here is my code so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class Other extends JFrame{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public Other() {
            super("Buttons");
            final Container mainPanel = getContentPane();
            mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
            inputPanel.add(new JLabel("RANDOM TEXT HERE"));
            inputPanel.add(new JLabel("RANDOM TEXT HERE"));
            inputPanel.add(new JLabel("RANDOM TEXT HERE"));
            JButton s = new JButton("first");
            JButton l = new JButton("second");
            buttonPanel.add(s,BorderLayout.LINE_END);
            buttonPanel.add(l,BorderLayout.LINE_END); //<-- not working
            mainPanel.add(inputPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            mainPanel.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            pack();
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setVisible(true);
        }
   public static void main(String[] args){
       Other o = new Other();
   }
}
```

Comment: A BorderLayout is probably not the right layout manager for what you want to do. Oracle has a good tutorial on selecting the right layout manager, or you could use a GUI builder in an IDE like NetBeans. Here's the turorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: This is how you can do it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379512/aligning-jbuttons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
```

While the `BorderLayout` will only accept one component per layout area, `FlowLayout` will display as many as are added (within viewable bounds).

Comment: Thanks I also thought of a solution I could have just gotten rid of layout on the buttonPanel then just add the buttonPanel to the mainPanel with a BorderLayout.LINE_END

Answer (score 0):

you can design GUI better and easy with Netbeans 7.1 .. you can align the swing components wherever you like and even make dependent on size of the frame ... you can get it here https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html